# Html to SVG coordinates

Tags: jquery, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to drag an element from HTML page and drop it into SVG. How would i convert the drop coordinates to coordinates on the SVG ?

im currently using d3 on the svg and jquery to drag drop the element. Appreciate the help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function coordinateTransform(screenPoint, someSvgObject)
{
  var CTM = someSvgObject.getScreenCTM();
  return screenPoint.matrixTransform( CTM.inverse() );
}
```

screenPoint being the point in your drop event.

Here is a JS Fiddle which may help: https://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/e5q6vnLt/